# How to implement kanban principles into one's personal life?

Tags: personal-skills, kanban

I'm impressed with kanban from a team perspective, and I'd like to suggestions on how to implement kanban from a personal perspective.

Answer (score 2):

You might try [personalkanban.com](http://www.personalkanban.com/pk/). The site is dedicated to applying Kanban in personal life.

Answer (score 1):

There was a great podcast on this about a year ago ... where a developer introduced it into his home life and the kids were able to get out of the house more effectively in the morning ...

... After some searching its [Elegant code #31 - Agile for Families](http://elegantcode.com/2009/08/31/code-cast-31-agile-for-families/). Great discussion on applying the same principals within the home.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get a look at [this blog on Agile and Family](http://agileandfamily.blogspot.com/), especially assigned to implement agile in our family with our kids.

There is also a great book called ["Agile Kids"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005C2097A).

Answer (score 1):

Or just have a board and start doing it like my friend did (http://bit.ly/mFCee3):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to feel a need to organize your life. 
Second of all - follow simple personal kanban rules to build your own personal kanban board:

1. Establish Your Value Stream
2. Establish Your Backlog
3. Establish Your WIP Limit
4. Begin to Pull

Good luck!