# Personal time management challenges causing Stress & Anxiety

Tags: time-management, training, task-management

Last month I was assigned my first job about project management.

But I realized that honestly, I have a problem with time management. I feel always stressed and anxious. More time thinking about things that I should do, than doing it.

This mixture of anxiety and stress is basically killing me psychologically.

So I guess I need some advice (article, blog, book, etc) to start fixing myself about time management, I think this should reduce a lot my anxiety and stress.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Check out some threads at productivity.stackexchange.com. How to prevent from being overwhelmed: http://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/916/how-to-prevent-from-being-overwhelmed . I would also check out the tag on that site regarding `time management`

Answer (score 5):

I've found a personal Kanban board very useful. Kanban allows you to limit your work in progress. I use [LeanKitKanban](http://leankitkanban.com/), and restrict myself to 3 things on the go at any time, with 6 things (about a week's work) in a backlog. Ongoing concerns take up one of my "in progress" slots. I also have a "waiting" column which I limit to 4, which means that if I want to wait for someone else I have to chase up an existing problem to free the space.

This really helps me to finish one thing before I start another, and to say "No" if I'm already booked up or have too many ongoing concerns.

LeanKitKanban has icons and different colours, so I can also visualise deadlines, things which have slow feedback loops but will come back to bite me later, small tasks vs. big projects, tasks which need to be expedited, repeating tasks, etc.

+1 for Pawel's suggestion of "Getting Things Done", which amongst other helpful suggestions says that if it takes 5 minutes, just do it (and don't put it on the Kanban board).

These two posts can be helpful in terms of pointing resources on personal Kanban:

- [How to implement kanban principles into one's personal life?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/3056/how-to-implement-kanban-principles-into-ones-personal-life)
- [Does anyone use a personal Kanban / Scrum board for project management activities?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/2009/does-anyone-use-a-personal-kanban-scrum-board-for-project-management-activities)

Answer (score 3):

If you look for a book I would start with [Getting Things Done](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0142000280). You can also check [author's website](http://www.davidco.com/) as there are some resources there as well.

However, in terms of being productive I find a couple of simple rules very useful. Focus on a single thing at any moment, which means you don't lose time on context switching and actually start doing, and finishing, tasks. To get yourself into the flow you can start with tasks which are easier to complete and then move to bigger ones. BTW: I sometimes work that way and call it "[do it now day](http://blog.brodzinski.com/2008/02/do-it-now-day.html)."

Comment: In addition to the book, there is a great podcast: http://gtd-vsg.blogspot.de/ The group is open for everybody, meets every 2 weeks per telephone conference, and discusses everything about GTD and beyond. I have found the podcasts to be very inspiring, because it is made by ordinary people, who all struggle but also succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly on Time Management, but on stress that you are facing. **Try to work less**. I know that it may sound a little bit odd, but thinking and / or working more and more will make you less efficient.

Go for a walk, go swimming, go to a gym, have a beer. Go to bed earlier instead of working late. Physical activity will relax your brain after a hard day and you will see that the following day you will work more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Expect to be a little stressed.  You are doing something new and unfamiliar, and you are out of your comfort zone.  As you get experience you will become more comfortable.

There are lots of books on Time Management.  Some may work for you and other will not.  Stop by your local library and browse their offerings.  While you are there, review their offerings on Project Management.  Don't be afraid to ask the librarian for assistance, they may be able to suggest other useful resources.

Getting Things Done is quite popular, but it can be overwhelming.  However, the techniques may help you track and organize what you need to do.  Try to use it for incoming stuff, and gradually add in your backlog.  The two minute rule may help in deciding whether to do it now or later.  There is a [podcast](http://gtd-vsg.blogspot.com/) study group on GTD that you may find helpful, it is available for iPhone or iPad.

Try to limit the major things you plan to do on a give day to a very short list.  Gather smaller task of similar types as a group.

Answer (score 0):

*I used to have precisely the opposite problem; I would not consider any task pressing enough to prioritize it accordingly and my delivery would suffer quite badly.*

### 100 Day System

I devised the following method to become more productive and I recommend to everyone; it uses a standard notebook (Moleskin, Leuchturm, etc) and divides the day into two components

- Productive Output
- Creative Output

**You can find the methodology in this [SlideShare](http://www.slideshare.net/stevenfeeney/10-reasons-why-google-journal-is-changing-the-game-24448822) << LINK which gives you more than enough to get started.**  *Disclaimer* : Ignore the front page; it was a marketing hook for viewers because I originally planned to turn the methodology into a fully published book.

### Reception

The system of time management was praised by [GeekDad](http://geekdad.com/2013/07/increase-productivity-with-100ds/), [43 Things](http://www.43things.com/things/view/18313/prioritize) and a few other productivity [outlets](http://www.trainingzone.co.uk/anyanswers/question/time-management-avoiding-procrastination/187659).  It was also elevated to the front page of SlideShare and rated as one of their Top 10 Presentations of the year. (They sent me a little email and stuff haha)